# Add filter to the_title only for the_title function

Tags: wordpress

Since `the_title()` and `the_title_attribute()` function use the same function `get_the_title()` to retrieve the title, is there a way to add `the_title` filter only for `the_title()` function?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that since neither `the_title` nor `the_title_attribute` offer any filters. Like you say, they call `get_the_title` which is where the `the_title` filter is. But you could easily copy the code of `the_title` and make your own version of it.

Comment: It is not a good idea to ask user to change all `the_title()` function in their template to the `copied_the_title()` function.

Comment: You didn't say you were writing a plugin. It's a good idea only if you 're writing a theme. In your case, then, I guess the answer is that there is no solution.

Comment: Yes @Calle, I don't know why WordPress use the same filter for it, or the same function that also use the same filter.

Comment: Perhaps they intend to change it. For example, there is one filter for get_excerpt and another for get_the_excerpt even though get_excerpt simply echoes get_the_excerpt, so it seems to me a bit inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me.

```
add_filter('the_title', 'somefilter');
function somefilter($title)
{
     $tr=debug_backtrace();
     $out='';
     foreach ($tr as $v){
         if (strpos($v['function'], 'title')) {
             $out.=$v['function'];
         }
    }
    if ($out!='get_the_titlethe_title') {
         return $title;
    }
    /** some filtering of the_title()
    but not get_the_title() can be placed below **/
}
```